# Accessing WPF UserControl child element property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Let's say I have a UserControl with several child controls

```
<UserControl x:Class="Any.AnyControl"
    <Grid>
        <Label Name="label1" Background="Black" />
        ... more controls here  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and I use it in MainWindow like so:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
         <local:AnyControl/>
         // I want to access AnyControl label1 Background property here 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know how I can access AnyControl label1 Background property in code-behind, but is there any way I can access it in parent XAML?

my code now:
in parent XAML

```
<local:AlertControl LabelBackground="Blue">
```

in UserControl

```
  <Label Background="{Binding LabelBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

and try with this too

```
<Label Background="{Binding LabelBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AlertControl}}" />
```

Comment: The UserControl should expose a property, e.g `LabelBackground`, to which the Label's Background is bound like `<Label Background="{Binding LabelBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still don't know how I can access this way in parent XAML. Please, could you give me an example?

Comment: Like `<local:AnyControl LabelBackground="Red"/>`. LabelBackground should be a dependency property in AnyControl, as shown in the duplicate question.

Comment: I copy paste your code but it doesn't work for me, says "The property 'LabelBackground' does not exist in XML namespace ..."

Comment: Sure, you first have to add it to your UserControl's class declaration.

Comment: I did so of course

Comment: You probably did something wrong, and may want to read this first: [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties)

Comment: yes, I think so. I edited my question with my code, still error

Comment: There's no dependency property declaration. Please read the article linked in my previous comment. Also take a closer look at the duplicate question.

Comment: "There's no dependency property declaration" you mean in code-behind? As I said I know how I can this property in code-behind but want to access it in XAML without any code-behind magic. Sorry, it looks my question was not 100% clear. Sorry about this

Comment: A dependency property in a UserControl is by no means any "code-behind magic". All control properties are declared in code behind. There's no way to avoid that. You may als want to read [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Comment: This is why I think might be not the dependency property is what I'm looking for. I just want to reuse this control at several places with a very little modification, eg. background colors are different at each controls but the whole control is same otherwise. Thanks for your suggestion I will read those docs

Comment: I thought and hoped may be there is a way where I can access UserControl property in parent XAML like this: UserControl.Name.property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this (although it's not the best practice to style controls in their parent control):

```
<local:AnyControl>
    <local:AnyControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </local:AnyControl.Resources>
</local:AnyControl>
```

It sets the background property for all controls of a given type inside your UserControl. If you want to change it for a control selected by a name, you can do something like that (change `Value="Test"` to your control's name):

```
<local:AnyControl>
    <local:AnyControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Name" Value="Test">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </local:AnyControl.Resources>
</local:AnyControl>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, this should work but I think it is too complicated so better to modify that property with one line of code in code-behind then.

Comment: I know, you are right, that's why I set your answer as answer. thank you

Comment: Please keep in mind that if you split styling controls to both xaml files and code behind it gets significantly harder to maintain. In most cases it's better to keep your code at one place, even if it's taking a bit more space, especially if it comes to styling in xaml, which doesn't go along too well with debugger (which means that it mostly doesn't work at all). Also you haven't set my answer as an answer

Comment: Thanks for you further suggestions. I set your answer as answer but I need to have 15 points or what to be shown my vote publicly

Comment: Really, sorry. I'm very new here